# Когда "онлайн" спереди - дефис, а когда позади?

Tags: заимствования, приложение, дефис

> На протяжении лет эти заметки о погоде, бытовые сценки, цитаты из
>   мудрых трудов, с которыми я провожу время, были доступны только моим
>   **друзьям онлайн**.

Онлайн-друзья, да? А друзья(?)онлайн?

Comment: В таком варианте, мне кажется, можно прочитать "доступны онлайн".

Comment: Тёмыч, а если я неверно прочла? А прав ты? Тире перед онлайном, чтоб не путаться? Иди ответ давай!

Comment: Тире совсем не понимаю зачем.

Comment: Эх ты, а ещё друг... Вот етого ***(как)*** я как читатель и не прочла, даже не заподозрила.

Comment: В смысле "а ещё друг..."?)))

Comment: А ты разве недруг? ворог? О_о

Comment: Я сначала просто подумал, что это ко мне обращение! =))

Comment: Так всё-таки это было ко мне? Я конечно же друг, просто в какой связи эта ирония "эх ты, а ещё...", не пойму...

Comment: В смысле, надо было сразу брать быка за рога и объяснить, что *возможно моё неверное прочтение*. А ты про зачем тире.

Comment: Да, вот не взял быка... Я просто исходил как из аксиомы, что должны быть эти онлайн-друзья и что тут непременно такой смысл. Не понял сразу этой фразы правильно: *Тёмыч, а если я неверно прочла? А прав ты?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне вариант ***онлайн-друзья*** больше всего нравится. Только вот не знаю, с дефисом оставить или без. По-английски было бы без, просто прилагательное+существительное. А в выделенном варианте можно прочитать *"были доступны друзьям **(как?) онлайн**".* Правда, если дефис поставить и в таком перевёрнутом варианте, такой вариант прочтения отпадёт.

Итак, оказалось, что смысл действительно в том, что *всё это было доступно друзьям **(каким образом?) онлайн**.* Галина неверно истолковала фразу.

Comment: ***На протяжении лет эти заметки о погоде, бытовые сценки, цитаты из мудрых трудов, с которыми я провожу время, были доступны онлайн только моим друзьям...*** - вот так понятно; что-то автор нам скажет? за манипулейшн?

Comment: Да вроде всё понятно. Так смысл такой, что ли, получается, а не онлайн-друзья?

Comment: Автор наблюдает, обо что мы спотыкаемся. Если можно сделать текст прозрачней простой перестановкой слов, отчего бы не сделать? сделает. )))

Comment: Да, если в цитате оригинал, выходит, что действительно доступны (как?) онлайн, скорее всего.

Answer (score 2):

Если это *определение* для друзей, то **онлайн-друзья**: несмотря на функцию прилагательного, заимствованное слово лишено русского окончания, которое позволяло бы его воспринимать как *прилагательное*; поэтому нужно образовывать сложное слово через дефис. Аналогичный пример заимствования: "**компакт-диск**" (= компактный диск) - в английском же слова пишутся раздельно, а функция прилагательного распознаётся через порядок слов. Если же слову "онлайн" придаётся функция *наречия*, то трудно сказать, **что хуже** с точки зрения распознавания его в русском как такового без формальных признаков (напр. окончания): оставить как есть (по аналогии с ранее заимствованными "де-факто", "тет-а-тет") или "приделать" предлог ("в онлайне" - помимо хождения такой фигуры речи есть даже предприятия с таким названием). Нужно ли употребление этого  заимствования в качестве наречия, покажет время, а пока что оно производит впечатление чего-то недопереведённого (словечек вроде "юзера"); проще и яснее выглядит "в сети".

В исходном варианте с постпозицией слова нельзя понять, идёт ли речь о доступности только в сети или о друзьях, находящихся в сети; реальны эти друзья или виртуальны.

Comment: Саша, спасибо тебе большое. Если б были возможны две ЛОшки... Последний абзац твоего ответа полетит к автору как птиса белая, особ статьёй. *Лети с приветом, вернись с ответом!*

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: даже если вопрос отпал, всё равно предлагаю его разобрать.

Артём все верно сказал. Действительно могут существовать два схожих сочетания: онлайн-друзья и друзья онлайн.

Для удобства начнём разбирать второе сочетание:

**Друзья онлайн — самая лучшая вещь в мире**

Чтобы нас не путало заимствованное слово "онлайн", заменим его русским аналогом "в сети":

**Друзья (какие?) в сети — самая лучшая вещь в мире**

Как видим, в данном случае "в сети" является несогласованным определением, что, очевидно, верно и для "онлайн".
А теперь предлагаю вспомнить правило согласованных и несогласованных определений:

**Данное несогласованное определение может быть преобразовано в согласованное, однако не всегда**

Слово "онлайн" является заимствованным и, насколько я знаю, **не имеет производных слов, образованных с помощью морфем, поэтому можно провести аналогию со словом "Интернет"**. Например, мы точно знаем, что сочетание "Интернет-друзья" пишется через дефис, причём здесь можно также подобрать несогласованное определение: друзья (какие?) из Интернета. Единственным отличием является то, что Интернет — имя собственное. Поэтому и пишем "онлайн-друзья" через дефис. Однако я всё же не до конца уверен в том, что данные слова являются определениями. По крайней мере, точно не согласованными ввиду их неизменяемости и, следовательно, невозможности согласования.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил свою логику.